# How to increase the height of progress component in antd

Tags: css, reactjs, components, progress-bar, antd

I have tried `height:'50px'` in style prop which is increasing the height of the container but not the progress bar.

I tried to target base classes as below which doesn't work as well.

```
.ant-progress-line .ant-progress-outer .ant-progress-inner div.ant-progress-bg {
  height: 50px;
}
```

how to achieve the expected behavior?
[image]

Comment: Please, provide the HTML code too for the clarification of how the classes are used in your HTML/JS file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
.ant-progress-bg {
    height: 20px !important;
}
```